# Chrome extension dev: use relative links in javascript files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've got something like...

```
img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "image.png";
```

However, image.png throws back a 404 error that the file cannot be found. When it is infact there in the relativepath. This same code works when linking to an image at a web address. Is there a work around for this? how can I use relative URL's in my Chrome extension?

Comment: Not really an answer but what I do is just make a path variable in my script that is the base path of the website. Then I set all of my images and such to absolute paths using that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chrome extensions you must use getURL()

```
img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = chrome.extension.getURL('image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = window.location.origin + "/image.png";
```